# How to add base64 encoded files to simple javascript form?

Tags: javascript, forms, base64

I have N files in base64 format inside an object and a simple form like so:

```
var files = {
    'foo.pdf': 'JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8u...',
    'bar.pdf': 'JVBERi0xLjUNCiWCiU...'
}

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.name = 'stupidInternetExplorerFixForm';
form.method = 'POST';
form.action = config.API_URL + '/foobar.pdf';

function appendField(key, value) {
   var tmp = document.createElement('input');
   tmp.type = 'HIDDEN';
   tmp.name = key;
   tmp.value = value;
   form.appendChild(tmp);
}

appendField('foo', 'foo');
appendField('bar', 'bar');
//appendField('files', files); -- HERE. What do I do here?

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

This form will always return a file. How do I add the files to my form programmatically? This has to work with IE9 and above. Changing the content-type is potentially possible, but I'd like to avoid it if possible. Backend is Java (Spring) and all kind of trickery there is no problem.

---

EDIT: Ajax file download is not an option at this point, it was already attempted before this method was tried. Basically I am actually creating a fallback option for ajax file downloads with multiple file uploads inside it. **The solution**: Upload the files as dynamic text fields instead of actual real files. Then in the backend convert them into files again.

Comment: @rugdealer Yes. My main functional does exactly that. But - I need it to return a file that's not stored anywhere (only in ram). Decent browsers can handle this and I can open the file with `new Blob([data], {type: datatype})`, but ... ahem... other browsers cannot. So I need to default back to this stupid method for those browsers.

Comment: @rugdealer Sending is not the issue. The issue is what gets returned. The server has to return a file. If I do an AJAX request, I cannot do anything with the file that gets returned. With this method, the file gets opened in the browser. `add the base64 string to a hidden input's value` - do you mean create N input fields dynamically for this? That might be a possibility actually, I'll just have to find out how to create a spring databinding for that. Add that as an answer while I check it out on the backend and Spring docs.

Comment: @rugdealer recreating the file is no prob. It's the databinding. The file download works already, fine but those libraries tend not to like dynamic file uploads that are not included in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities in accomplishing what you're trying to do.

Suppose we're going to go ahead and go with your original idea in creating a form programatically and adding hidden inputs dynamically. You can reuse your existing function you created to add the files since you already have your files in a string format.

```
for(var fileName in files){
  if(!files.hasOwnProperty(fileName)) continue;
  appendField(fileName, files[fileName]);
}
```

Then you can send the form with all your files as inputs.

Comment: Thanks! I already use an ajax file download, this workaround will be for browsers that are unable to do handle ajax file downloads, so basically I am re-implementing what for example jquery.fileDownload does on lines 323-348 in https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js#L323 -- but I just need to add a file N times and I didn't know how. Now I do and the answer that you gave me really was: Don't treat them as files, treat them as generic Strings and make Files out of them in the server

Comment: @Nenotlep glad to help. Good luck.